# How to have focused Input form with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using Bootstrap 3.0.0 and I want to use the focused input form:
[See here, under Form States.. input focus](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#forms-controls-static)

I have used `<input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" value="This is focused...">` this to get it as focused, but I'm not getting that. Documentation said to use `:focus` to get focused but I don't know how.

some code in bootstrap.css

```
.form-control {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 34px;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  color: #555555;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: 1px solid #cccccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
  -webkit-transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
          transition: border-color ease-in-out 0.15s, box-shadow ease-in-out 0.15s;
}

.form-control :focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They present there only a focus demo. The `#focusedInput` styles come from `docs.css` and it's used just to force the focused look. That isn't included in Bootstrap pack, but only in documentation pages, as you can see in the following screen shoot (see: `docs.css:1072`):

[image]

Then we have to create a CSS class that will have the focused styles:

```
.focusedInput {
    border-color: rgba(82,168,236,.8);
    outline: 0;
    outline: thin dotted \9;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6);
    box-shadow: 0 0 8px rgba(82,168,236,.6) !important;
}
```

Now, only including `focusedInput` class in HTML input elements, you will be able to set focus styles for non-focused elements.

```
<input class="form-control focusedInput" type="text" value="This is focused...">
```

See the [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3nHP/3/)

---

`:focus` selector is used for setting the styles for focused state of input.

[**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/m3nHP/)

[For example](http://jsfiddle.net/m3nHP/1/):

```
#focusedInput:focus {
    background: red;
}
```

This will set red background when you focus the input.

Comment: yes, working fine but, I think according to documentation I don't need to add anything. I just want to know how to use that :focus.

Comment: I'm not able to state my problem clearly.
As we see the code for a input form is 
<input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" value="This is focused...">
the focus is also in the form-control class.
how to use this focus in the code mentioned above.
I tried using <input class="form-control:focus" id="focusedInput" type="text" value="This is focused...">, but didn't get what I wanted

Comment: @Lonely No, don't use `class="form-control:focus"` because it's invalid. Create a class like I've described in the edited answer.

Comment: I opened [the issue](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/9971) on the Bootstrap repository from Github.

Answer (score 26):

You can achieve what you want by setting the autofocus attribute inside the input tag to autofocus.
The keyboard input will be focused on the input field and it will glow.

```
<input class="form-control" id="focusedInput" type="text" autofocus="autofocus" value="This is focused...">
```

Comment: If used within a modal, this will only work the first time the modal is opened

Answer (score 2):

```
$("#inputID").focus(); // will bring focus
$("#inputID").addClass("focusedInput"); // will give it the bootstrapped focus style
scrollTo("#confirm_deletion"); // actually make browser go to that input

/* scroll to the given element section of the page */
function scrollTo(element)
{
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $(element).offset().top-60}, 500);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just needed to remove the space between the :focus selector on the .form-control class.

```
.form-control:focus {
  border-color: #66afe9;
  outline: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075), 0 0 8px rgba(102, 175, 233, 0.6);
}
```

[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/giovannif23/5mpF7/1/)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem so i tried to search the css of bootstrap. i had download one theme of bootswatch and replace it with the bootstrap so that might be the problem in my case. Anyhow what i found was that the `form-control:focus` had `outline:0` that means it was disabling the focus effect. i erased that line and worked like a charm.Try it if anyone has the same problem.Hope it helped.